# Erratic Mouse Behavior

Tags: drivers, 18.10, mouse-pointer

I'm having an issue on my desktop computer where my mouse pointer sticks to the edges of my screen, typically the top right corner, and any attempt to move it away will cause it to snap back to that position like a rubber band. Because of this, I am unable to use my mouse.

I was able to resolve this issue by blacklisting the `psmouse` module in `/etc/modprobe.d`, as recommended by [Dell (and on the Ubuntu forums a few years ago) here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln304721/erratic-cursor-movement-on-the-xps-13-15-series-laptops-and-precision-mobile-workstations-with-ubuntu-1604-installed?lang=en).

However, blacklisting the psmouse module causes resume from suspend issues. Specifically, after suspend, my mouse will move very slowly and have a stutter/lag to it, and my audio will stutter. When I launch the psmouse module, both the mouse and audio issue go away, but I am then unable to use my mouse again.

I am currently running a fresh installation of Pop!_OS 18.10, but have confirmed the issue exists on latest Ubuntu LTS and 18.10

My system is using Nvidia 410 drivers and an i7-4770K. The issues persist regardless of the connected peripherals. I have tried different mice, keyboards, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions for resolving the mouse issue without blacklisting or removing psmouse via modprobe?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I allowed the mouse to exhibit it's odd behavior and was able to run `xinput` while it was doing so.

`xinput` revealed an entry called "PS/2 Generic Mouse". Disabling this generic device allowed my mouse to work normally without having to blacklist psmouse. You can disable it with the command

```
xinput disable id#
```

If you want to disable a xinput pointer entry permanently, you can do so by creating "xorg.conf" in     /etc/X11 and entering the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier         "disable broken device"
   MatchIsPointer     "on"
   MatchProduct       "PS/2 Generic Mouse"
   Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Credit goes to [this Stack Exchange Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278333/how-can-i-permanently-disable-a-xinput-device)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a touch screen laptop and facing this issue, try disabling the touch screen. That was what worked in my case.

Here is how to disable it.

First list out all the registered input devices by running the command

```
xinput
```

You should have something like this
[image]

Locate the id of the touch screen input (which is `id=10` in my case)

Then run the following command to disable it

```
xinput disable <your_id>
```

Comment: I didn't have any Elan touch-screen on my Dell 9570, but I had three Wacom HID 488E (Pen stylus, Pen eraser and Finger touch). Disabling all of them did the trick.